# ALGLIB Spline1dConvcubic goes terribly wrong

Tags: c#, interpolation, alglib

I have the following code to do spline interpolation in C# with ALGLIB:

```
void interpolateData() // Spline 1D convcubic
{
    int anzNeueWerte = Convert.ToInt32(
                   Interaction.InputBox("Enter the new number of x-values:"
                                            ", x.Length / 2 + "", 500, 500));
    double[] xNeu = new double[anzNeueWerte];           double[] yNeu;
    double tempXNeu = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < xNeu.Length; i ++)
    {
        xNeu[i] = tempXNeu
        tempXNeu += ((double) x.Length / anzNeueWerte);
    }

    alglib.spline1dconvcubic(x, y, xNeu, out yNeu);

    for(int i = 0; i < y.Length; i ++)
    {
        vorher.Add(new PointPair(x[i], y[i]));
        Debug.WriteLine("Vorher:" + vorher.ElementAt(i).ToString());
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < yNeu.Length; i ++)
    {
        nachher.Add(new PointPair(xNeu[i], yNeu[i]));
        Debug.WriteLine("Nachher:" + nachher.ElementAt(i).ToString());
    }

    CreateGraph();
}
```

I've already checked the input values, in case they are read falsely, and they are correct. The only thing that goes wrong is the line with **alglib.spline1dconvcubic(..)**. I don't know if the calculation doesn't work or if I just write it in a way where the decimal points are for some reason in very different places.

The variable **anzNeueWerte** (german) determines the new number of x-Values for the dataset. The variables **xNeu** and **yNeu** are double arrays that contain the new x- and y-values.

The last line, **CreateGraph()** just calls the method for drawing the ZedGraph chart, which works **as it should**, so the problem is neither in this line nor the method it calls.

I already had it working last week, and I'm almost sure I haven't changed anything since then.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** The y-values should be in a range of 0-8000, but go from a little over zero to about -320.000.000.000.000

P.S.: **Don't** mark this question as off-topic, duplicate or anything else. **None** of the questions I could find about this library contains **anything useful** for my problem.

Comment: Have you tried any of the alternative [spline interpolation functions](http://www.alglib.net/interpolation/spline3.php) in ALGLIB and obtained similar results? Have you tested spline interpolation using an alternative numerics library, e.g. [Math.NET Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/)?

Comment: I tried other functions, but for some reason, they don't work when I want to calculate more x-Points than I had before and lead to an OutOfMemory Exception. And Math.NET Numerics doesn't work in my project, as it includes the reference, but won't let me include the namespace.

Comment: Could you include a code example where you use alternative functions, because as far as I can tell from the user manual you need to perform interpolation with the other functions in a two-step-process (build interpolator, then interpolate single points), right? Sounds strange that it would yield an `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: I don't have those code examples anymore, because it was too much code to leave in my main project. But I can clear up your confusion about the two steps: With the normal functions (those that lead to the `OutOfMemoryException`), I have to build a `SplineInterpolant` first and then iterate through my data, that's right. But with the function I'm currently using (`spline1dconvcubic()`), this isn't necessary.

Comment: Yes, I understand that `spline1dconvcubic` is a convenience method; as far as I can tell it is only the cubic spline that provides such a convenience method, right? That's why I thought it would be valuable to see the code where you are not using a convenience method. The code in the manual seems pretty straightforward even without the convenience method, so I thought it would be interesting to compare your approach with the user manual approach.

Comment: My first approach without a convenience method just copying the code from the manual and running it on the computer I work on. But that doesn't work.